# ClickOnce in Release mode doesn't publish

Tags: clickonce, release

Just doing some testing/prototyping with ClickOnce. Does anyone know why I can publish with CLickOnce when its set to 'debug' mode but not when its set to 'release' mode?

I dont even get an error message for the latter. The output folder remains empty as nothing has happened.  Once I switch to Debug mode and do the publishing everything is fine.

Any idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry no, but you should try to both create a new config that copies the settings from the Release config and try to publish that one. Or even create a new config from scratch that sets the same flags as the release config.

If any of those work you might even remove the Release one and rename the new one to Release.

Comment: the problems doesnt happen in VS2010. Can't find a solution, so I close this.

Answer (score 0):

Is there anything in the \bin\release folder? It should have the binaries and everything included in the deployment, including the app.publish folder.